# Is the calculated loss associated with all samples or not?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am new to deep learning and Tensorflow.  I got some basic questions with the sample code below :

```
for j in range(no_of_training_sample):
    ...
    ...
    _, _loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], {X: x, Y: y})
```

1. For the value of `_loss` returned, is it the loss for each data sample or the sum from data sample 0 up to data sample j ?
2. When will the parameter w, h and b be updated, after each `sess.run()`?
3. How can I change the code to turn it into mini-batch ?

I tried to search the internet, I but cannot get quick answers from it.

Answer (score 0):

`_loss` is the returned value of `loss` (the second element in the list that you pass as first argument to the [`run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) function), after having executed a step of the [computation graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs) (TF is based on "static" executions of computation graphs which represent the operations that need to be run).

The loss can be defined in different ways (e.g. you can define it as the cross entropy between the predicted values and the target values), so the result you will obtain in `_loss` will depend not only on the data you pass to the session as second argument (in your case `{X: x, Y: y}`), but also on the way you compute the loss.

The parameters of your network are updated when, in the computation graph, e.g., the function [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize) is called.

To change the code and make it use mini-batches (rather than the full dataset at once), instead of passing `x` and `y` to the placeholders `X` and `Y` in the expression `{X: x, Y: y}` (when you call `, _loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], {X: x, Y: y})`), you will have to create an "iterator" which gives you a subset of `x` (and the corresponding `y`) that you can pass to `X` (and `Y` respectively). You can actually use one of the new TF APIs which facilitate this task (instead of creating the iterator from scratch).

(If you had just asked one question, my answer could have been more detailed).